# Internal Vrs External Path to Sub-repository

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I have a repository for an application A which is controlled by mercurial and a library B which is also controlled by mercurial. In the application A's repository it has the sub-repository mapped to library B's repository using the path central repository path **ssh://user@1.2.3.4/B**. This works well enough for our internal development, but we need access externally, but we can't use the domain name as our router bulks. Is it possible to have the sub-repository defined as something like:

```
[internal]
B = ssh://user@1.2.3.4/B
[external]
B = ssh://user@domain/B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only method that I was able to find, which sort of works, is to have each developer [set the path](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SubrepoRemappingPlan) for the repository. So for the example above, the path for an internal developer would remain unchanged, but the external developers would change their sub-paths to:

```
ssh://user@1.2.3.4/B = ssh://user@domain/B
```

Comment: This is sort of what we do as well. Not that tricky, since you only have to do it once per user, since you can use regexps to avoid repeating yourself.